# Problemas con los patrones en JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con la introducción con los patrones por teclado en JAVA. Resulta ser que intento que me de tres intentos para introducir una clave y posteriormente, justo después de cumplir con las tres opciones me salga incorrecto, pero que si lo escribo bien en cualquiera de los tres intentos me diga "Correcto".

```
public class Ejercicio81a {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    String clave;
    int intentos = 3;
    int maximo = 0;

    System.out.println("Introduce la clave: ");
    clave = teclado.nextLine();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z]{4})([0-9]{3})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(clave);

    do {
        intentos--;
        System.out.println("Intento nº: " + intentos);

        if ((m.equals(clave))&&(intentos>maximo)) {
            System.out.println("Correcto.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrecto");
            System.out.println("Introduzca la clave nuevamente: ");
            clave = teclado.nextLine();
        }

    } while ((m.find()) && (intentos > maximo));}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo por aquí un ejemplo muy parecido al tuyo, el cual creo que puede ayudarte.

**Código:**

```
public class Ejercicio81a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        String clave;
        String claveBuscar = "PasswordSegura";
        int intentos = 3;


        while(intentos != 0) {
            System.out.println("Tienes: " + intentos+" para introducir la contraseña correctamente");

            System.out.print("Introduce la clave: ");
            clave = teclado.nextLine();

            if(claveBuscar.equals(clave)) {
                 System.out.println("Contraseña correcta.");
                 break;
            }
            else
            {
                do{
                    intentos--;
                    if(intentos == 0)break;
                    System.out.println("Incorrecto");
                    System.out.println("Te quedan: "+intentos+" restantes");
                    System.out.print("Introduzca la clave nuevamente: ");                   
                    clave = teclado.nextLine();

                    if(claveBuscar.equals(clave)) {
                        System.out.println("Contraseña correcta.");
                        break;
                    }

                 }while(!claveBuscar.equals(clave));
             }

            if(intentos == 0 || claveBuscar.equals(clave))break;
        }

        if(intentos == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\n Lo sentimos, no te quedan mas intentos");
        }
    }   
}
```

He puesto como `String` una password para poder hacer el ejercicio. Con la ayuda de un ciclo `while`, mientras que el numero de intentos sea distinto de `0` que haga dichas comprobaciones.

```
if(claveBuscar.equals(clave)) {
    System.out.println("Contraseña correcta.");
    break;
}
```

Cuando encuentre la contraseña a la primera, mostrara un mensaje de afirmación y terminara el bucle con `break` y con ello el programa.

Luego tenemos en el `else`:

```
 do{
     intentos--;
     if(intentos == 0)break;
     System.out.println("Incorrecto");
     System.out.println("Te quedan: "+intentos+" restantes");
     System.out.print("Introduzca la clave nuevamente: ");                   
     clave = teclado.nextLine();

     if(claveBuscar.equals(clave)) {
         System.out.println("Contraseña correcta.");
         break;
     }

}while(!claveBuscar.equals(clave));
```

Aquí básicamente vamos quitando los números de intentos al poner la contraseña incorrecta. Cuando el numero de intentos sea `0` el bucle `do while();` terminará.

Mientras queden intentos, si se introduce la contraseña correcta, mostrar un mensaje de afirmación y con el `break` saldremos del bucle `do while();`

Con esto comprobamos, si los intentos están a `0` o si la clave se encontró, para terminar con el bucle `while`

```
if(intentos == 0 || claveBuscar.equals(clave))break; // claveBuscar.equals(clave) devuelve true si encuentra la clave
```

Y por ultimo, una validación para mostrar un mensaje diciendo que no tenemos mas intentos:

```
if(intentos == 0)
{
    System.out.println("\n Lo sentimos, no te quedan mas intentos");
}
```

Espero que haya sido de utilidad!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es lo que necesitas:

```
public class Ejercicio81a {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    String clave;
    int maximo = 0, intentos = 0;

    System.out.println("Introduce la clave: ");
    clave = teclado.nextLine();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z]{4})([0-9]{3})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(clave);

    for (intentos = 3; intentos > 0; intentos--) {
        System.out.println("Intento nº: " + intentos);

        if ((m.equals(clave)) && (intentos > maximo)) {
            System.out.println("Correcto.");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrecto");
            System.out.println("Introduzca la clave nuevamente: ");
            clave = teclado.nextLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Incorrecto");
    System.out.println("Intentos agotados");
}
```

}

Lo que no sé es cual es la clave correcta y por tanto no puedo comprobar esa parte, aún así espero que con estos cambios sea suficiente. Si no, por favor indícame de donde coges el valor de clave correcto.

Comment: La clave correcta es acde245.